# Not able to ssh into VM instance that was running on custom port

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We were running our sshd on a custom port and now we seem to not have access to the instance

We have tried to reboot the instance, change the disk size

```
    gcloud compute ssh rl --zone us-east1-b --ssh-flag=“-vp 25”
    OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to 35.XXX.XX.38 [35.227.46.38] port 25.
    debug1: connect to address 35.XXX.XX.38 port 25: Connection refused
    ssh: connect to host 35.XXX.XX.38 port 25: Connection refused
    ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error messages indicate that the connection was refused, which indicates that SSHD is running on your server or you are connecting to the wrong machine running SMTP. The opposite is "connection timed out" which indicates a firewall blocking access. I will list different methods for analyzing this problem.

Note: You are using TCP Port 25 which is typically used by SMTP. This is often blocked by policy by ISPs and corporate networks.

There are several possible problems that I can think of:

1. You do not have a firewall rule enabled on your GCE VM instance that allows SSH on the custom port.
2. The public IP address has changed. Double-check the IP address in the Google Console and compare with the address that you are using.
3. The SSH daemon has crashed or is not starting up. Check your Stackdriver logs for this instance. You can also check the Compute Engine Serial Port output.
4. You have incorrect file permissions on the public key used for the connection (look in `~/.ssh` for the Google key pairs.
5. In some rare cases, an ISP or a company firewall could be blocking the port that you are using. Some companies consider outgoing SSH a security risk. See my note above regarding SMTP (Port 25).

[Interacting with the Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)

[Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/)

The first item that I would check is the public IP address and verify that you are connecting to the correct machine.

Next, I would check is the firewall rule that allows traffic on your custom port. Log in to the Google Cloud Console. Go to "VPC Network" -> "Firewall rules". Click on your rule that you have for the custom SSH port. Near the bottom of the screen will be a list of GCE VM instances that this rule applies to. If your instance is not in the list fix that. Verify the port number, IP ranges, etc.

Next, I would look in the Stackdriver logs for error messages during the startup of the VM. Look for messages regard SSHD. If you have not installed Stackdriver on your instance, then repeat checking the Serial Port output (see the documentation link above).